# How to persist authentication cookie throughout all subdomains?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So I did the migration from aspnetcore1.1 to aspnetcore2.0, and am wrestling with the new authentication setup in `Startup.cs`.

All of my websites share the same domain '.example.com'. The user signs in using their Google account and is then issued an application cookie which I want to persist across all subdomains of '.example.com'.

Right now, though, when the user signs in, a cookie is successfully created, however they get logged out of every other site in the domain. Can someone take a stab at this?

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...-snip-...

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".AuthCookie";
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddGoogle(options => { /* ...-snip...- */ });

    // ...-snip-...
}

public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...-snip-...

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // ...-snip-...
}
```

All of my apps share this same code in their `Startup.cs` files. Does it have something to do with using `CookieAuthenticationDefaults`? Or am I missing something in my `ConfigureApplicationCookie`?

Comment: If you have multiple applications, you need to set up data protection in a way that allows them to share their secrets. So a cookie created by one applicaiton is also valid for another one. See [the documentation for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing).

Comment: @poke Thank you for the link! I was able to successfully get it. I've posted my solution below. If you'd like to submit that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct for you.

Comment: No, that’s fine, you can just accept your own answer after a few days – you figured out how to make this work, not me, I just found the right part in the documentation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Looks like I needed to create a data protection provider [to share authentication cookies between applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing). Here are the working code changes:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"));

    options.Cookie.Name = ".AuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
    options.DataProtectionProvider = protectionProvider;
    options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(protectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2"));
});
```